# Video choppy on slower devices

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I have noticed how youtube can play videos on old smartphones with no lag. I have a 3 seconds long video that acts as an animation on my website, I have compressed the file size down to less than a megabyte and have waited for the "canplaythrough" eventlistener before playing the video, but the video still lags like crazy on my laptop. I made a system that loads videos that match the user's resolution that looks like this

```
 var resulution_list = [1280, 1408, 1536, 1664, 1792, 1920, 2560];

 var resulution_dict = {
   1280: "videos/render_animation_1280.mp4",
   1408: "videos/render_animation_1408.mp4",
   1536: "videos/render_animation_1536.mp4",
   1664: "videos/render_animation_1664.mp4",
   1792: "videos/render_animation_1792.mp4",
   1920: "videos/render_animation_1920.mp4",
   2560: "videos/render_animation_2560.mp4",
 };

 var resulution_goal = window.innerWidth;

 var closest_resulution = resulution_list.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
   return Math.abs(curr - resulution_goal) < Math.abs(prev - resulution_goal)
     ? curr
     : prev;
 });

 const video_url = resulution_dict[closest_resulution];

 var source = document.createElement("source");

 source.setAttribute("src", video_url);
 source.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");

 document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].appendChild(source);
```

But that did not seem to help at all.
My video tag looks like this:

`<video id="animation-video" class="video_first" style="opacity: 0;" controls preload>`

It is really important that the video plays without any lag.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not vote to close but I'll tell you what's wrong here... **(1)** _"I have noticed how youtube can play videos on old smartphones with no lag"_ Yes, but missing is what resolution in Youtube you are testing on the device? For example: It's not obvious if you're trying to compare a **360p** video from YT with your own video tag playing at **1792p** resolution. Did you note the tested video resolutions for equality?

Comment: **(2)** Why can't you **show a real example** of a Youtube video link and show how the same MP4 plays slower on your site? You can download YT videos using a tool like: [GetVideo](https://getvideo.at/en/). From there, can you prove that Youtube does not lag its own playing 720p whilst the same MP4 of 720p is somehow playing slow (or with lag)on your site?

Comment: **(3)** Your resolutions logic is flawed. A 1080p video is **still** a 1080p video on any screen size. For example: It's text is not suddenly pixelated on a `2560` display. You should only make different resolutions because of the various **internet speeds** (faster speeds can download a larger yet higher quality file), not because of user's screen size!!

Comment: **(4)** Try encoding your videos at **standardized video resolutions** (with ratios like **4:3** and **16:9**). The hardware (video chip) itself will take care of scaling it to any device's screen size. This is done using interpolation algorithms (eg: bicubic re-sampling). They are already optimized for video decoding to screen size.

Comment: **(5)** A supposed video resolution of `1792` sounds crazy, so I googled if such a thing exists and found this forum discussion: [1792 x 768. another useless resolution](https://hardforum.com/threads/1792-x-768-another-useless-resolution.1709427/). Nothing special to read... but the fact that such an opinion exists let's you know this is a **dodgy** number to work with...

Comment: **(6) Possible solutions to avoid playback lag**:  **(1)** Encode your MP4 at **Baseline Profile** (is the easiest mode to decode even for old hardware). Experiment with the **Level** setting. **(2)** Try setting a **lower bitrate** for the output video. **(3)** Try a **smaller resolution** like 480p or 720p and see if the graphics hardware still displays it an acceptable visual quality on your test screens (it should also be playing smoother).

Comment: So resolution does not have anything to do with the innerWidth to do?